# Is $ 5 $ the only number that cannot be expressed as $ p + x ^ y$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n,x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ where $n\ge3,y\ge2$ and $p$ is prime number.

For some $n$, $n$ can be expressed as $n=p+x^y$

**Example**

$3=2+1^y$

$15=7+2^3$

We can check, $5$ can't be expressed.

> **Question**
>
> > Is $ n=5 $ the only number that cannot be expressed as $ p + x ^ y$ ?

I checked, there are always pair for n=3 up to n = 50. Except $5$.

Comment: $5-p$ is either $2$ or $3$ and neither number can be expressed as a power of a natural number  given the conditions

Comment: https://oeis.org/A119748

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to OEIS, other such numbers include 1549 and 1771561.](https://oeis.org/A119748) It is apparently unknown whether there are any more.